# ASP.net site with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

Firstly - I am an IT Technician and didn't actually produce the code we are having these problems with - I am simply trying to get the code working within a site in IIS. Now our coder doesn't believe their is a problem with the code itself (written in Visual Studio 2010, in the .NET4 framework, sorry if this isn't detailed enough!)

This issue I'm having is this:

I have created the site in IIS7, enabled Windows Authentication, given full permissions for everyone to the folder (to rule out permission issues) and the error we get it this when browsing to it:

[image]
We've tried all different permission changes (NETWORK SERVICE etc), tried different app pools (right now it uses the DefaultAppPool), tried removing the `<authentication>` clause entirely from the code and set Windows Authentication in IIS, all to no avail!

Any input is much appreciated, you can also direct code questions as I we (myself and our programmer) are actively monitoring this post!

Comment: http://dotnet-magic.blogspot.com/2008/11/it-is-error-to-use-section-registered.html

Comment: I would run aspnet_regiis.exe on the iis server.

[aspnet_regiis.exe][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078197/determining-if-asp-net-is-properly-registered

Comment: Did you configure virtual directory as application?

Comment: Its even because you use different asp.net version pool, than the one you have configure your run your site.

Comment: @Aristos I don't know what you mean?

Comment: @Win That blog makes no sense if I'm honest :(

Comment: ...what's the error? did you remove it?

Comment: The last part of the error says "The error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."