# Uploaded Mvc project on Windows Server show directories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, windows-server

I have upload a multiple projects on Windows Server some are website & some are MVC projects, Website running fine on windows server, with Default.aspx but the MVC project have controller/action/index.cshtml sense so its not run, Show all directories in URL

```
Below Url Show Directories these are MVC /Api Projects

   http://api.daakpad.com/
   http://fmsdemo.daakpad.com/
   http://api.punjabpragati.in/

Website code working fine 

   http://pms.gravitasoft.com/    // this have  default.aspx file on root working fine
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking your IIS installation and its configuration with .NET.

1) Go through the Server Management interface and click 'Add Roles'. Or go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off. Ensure IIS is installed correctly with the requirements you will need.

2) Check if the .NET framework you require is installed correctly and registered with IIS. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1739794/1453651). To register follow these steps -

- Open command prompt
- Navigate to the .NET framework folder = Look at the section 'Finding the Correct Version of Aspnet_regiis.exe' of [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.140%29.aspx#findingthecorrectversion) to find the correct version of aspnet_regiis you might need.
- run this command 'aspnet_regiis -ir'

> Installs and registers ASP.NET 4. This option is the same as the -i option except that this option does not change the CLR version that is associated with any existing application pools.

Source: [MSDN - ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

3) Ensure your AppPool for the MVC application is running in integrated mode with a later version of .NET (I believe it should be 4).